# make nivo slider (jquery) work after ajax calling

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I have an ajax call for my content (blog.php), which has the jquery nivo slider. But the slider just won't appear! I first thought it is a conflict with lightbox or the slider, but without ajax calling the slider it works just fine together. I guess I need to make the jquery work explicitly after the ajax call. I tried $(document).ajaxStop(function()
and also $(document).ready, but it didn't work. (maybe I did it wrong?)
My code with the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nivoslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        var imgload = $('#imgload_txt'),
            imgshow = $('#imgshow_txt');
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({
          pauseOnHover: false,
          pauseTime: 6000,
          onImageLoad: function(img) {
            imgload.hide();
            imgload.text(img.data('src'));
            imgload.fadeIn();
          },
          onImageChange: function(img) {
            imgshow.hide();
            imgshow.text(img.data('src'));
            imgshow.fadeIn();
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the ajax content call (the slider is in blog.php):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.blog').on('click', function() {
          var href = $(this).attr('href');
          if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
               $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'0' }).empty();
          }
          $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'2000px' },function() {
               $('#loader').css({ border:'none', position:'relative', top:'24px', left:'48px', boxShadow:'none'}); 
               $('#ajax').load('blog.php ' + href, function() {
                    $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn('slow').colorFade({ 'fadeColor': '#0e0e0e'});
               });
          });
     }).click();
});
```

Comment: Every time you add new content to your page and want your js to work on it you have rebind the content to the js /  write js that automatically does it for you.

Comment: I am so new to this, I understand what you mean, but I don't know how to do this. Is there an example I can follow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925159/nivo-slider-how-to-call-slider-after-ajax-content-load. I haven't checked the answer completely but i think this will at least give some hint

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, but it doesn not work. maybe because my nivoslider is a modified version with lazy loading?  or I am doing everything wrong. dumb noobz like me should stick to playing with lego I guess :/

Comment: Try to read on the concept of binding events in javascript. Understand concepts before playing with them

Comment: ok, trying that, but would a delay in the slider function work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct in thinking that the `<div id="slider">` is also part of the new HTML that's being called in through the `.load()` query as well, you'd need to modify your `.nivoSlider()` calling like:

```
$(document).find('#slider').nivoSlider({
    //Options
});
```

Below I've adjusted your `.load()` to `.ajax()`, simply because `.load()` is sometimes a little funny when it comes to script execution (See the Docs). Furthermore, I've placed the `.nivoSlider()` initialisation in the success: function() callback, so the html awaiting, will definitely be there.

### Main.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nivoslider.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     $('.blog').on('click', function() {
          var href = $(this).attr('href');

          if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
               $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' })
                         .animate({ height:'0' })
                         .empty();
          }

          $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' })
                    .animate({ height:'2000px' }, function() {

               $('#loader').css({ border:'none',  
                                  position:'relative', 
                                  top:'24px', 
                                  left:'48px', 
                                  boxShadow:'none'}); 

               $.ajax({
                   url: 'blog.php ' + href,
                   success: function( newHtml ) {
                       //Load the blog content
                       $('#content').html( newHtml );
                       $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn('slow');

                       var imgload = $(document).find('#imgload_txt'),
                           imgshow = $(document).find('#imgshow_txt');

                       $(document).find('#slider').nivoSlider({
                             //Options.
                       });
                   }
               });
          });
     });
});
</script>
```

### Blog.php

```
<h1>My Slider</h1>
<div id="slider">
    <img src="#" id="imgslider" /> 
</div>
<div id="imgload_txt">Some Text</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work:


        $(window).load(function() {
        var imgload = $('#imgload_txt'),
            imgshow = $('#imgshow_txt');
        $(document).find('#slider').nivoSlider({

Comment: It says nothing. Just "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'colorFade' " which was there before (it's part of the ajax call animation) and worked with another slider (which I cannot use anymore)

Comment: Well, JavaScript stops executing when it finds an error, so anything afterwards will never happen, if you remove `colorFade` for now =)

Comment: So no more new errors appearing? Updated answer to include the nivoslider in the callback - `blog.php` is a php script with the `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nivoslider.js"></script>` correct?

Comment: yes, no errors appearing! and yes, nivoslider is in blog.php, which is being called into a div on the main page. he main page has nivoslider.js

Comment: wow, what an effort! thanks a lot!! I will try it and give feedback when it works! :)

Comment: Your exact code did not work, but it was the right solution! thanks a million! Now my life is not pointless anymore and I can be happy again!!  here the code:  
   $('#ajax').load('blog.php ' + href, function() {
    var imgload = $('#imgload_txt'),
            imgshow = $('#imgshow_txt');
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({
          //options of nivoslider...
          }
        });
    $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn('slow').colorFade({ 'fadeColor': '#0e0e0e'});
            });
        });
    }).click();
});

Comment: Awesome =)! Glad you're able to move forward now, hehe ;)

Answer (score 0):

i used this one to stop and start nivoslider maybe it's usefull for you, i dont see any ajax-call in your code but after ajax-success you should simply start() nivo-slider again,

```
   //freeze .nivo-slices 
    jQuery('#slider').data('nivoslider').stop();
    //re-Init 
    setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('#slider').data('nivoslider').start();
    }, 1850);
```

Comment: It's neatly tucked away but it's the `.load()` function that calls the Ajax =)

Comment: I tried this, but the problem is not that it stops working, it just doesn't show up at all

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your nivoSlider initialization function to callback function of $('#ajax').load.

And $(window).load(function() in blog.php it's not that you actually need. Try .ready()

Comment: I think I know what you mean with your first sentence, but I don't know exactly where to put it. Do you have an example with my code? That'd be great! :)